# Passing a Function to an annotation in dart

Tags: dart

I want to send a `Function` as a parameter to an annotation like this:

```dart
@JsonKey(fromJson: ...)
final int variable;
```

where `fromJson` is a `Function`, but it gives me this error:

```
Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
```

what is the solution? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask how you are actually using the function reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't write what you wanted for `...`, and that's the part that causes the problem.

The argument to the `fromJson` parameter must be a compile-time constant value because annotations must be constant.

The only constant function values are top-level or static functions, so you need to declare the function type want, let's say as static:

```dart
class MyClass {
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _variableFromJson)
  final int variable;
  
  static int _variableFromjson(dynamic json) => ...;
 
  ...
}
```

You can't write the function in-line as `(fromJson: (json) => ...)` because function expressions are not compile-time constant.